# Does a hidden/transparent element impact rendering performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

So I have a Polymer app that I am writing. I have written a non-polymer web-component for a loading overlay that I can show whilst Polymer is loading and when the app Websocket is connecting/reconnecting.

Here is an exert of some of the CSS I have to give an indication of what I am doing:

```
  .overlay {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
  }

  .overlay[opened] {
    opacity: 0.8;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }

  .loader {
    display: none;
  }

  .overlay[opened] .loader {
    display: block;
  }
```

Now this overlay and the CSS based loader animation I have is only used when I load the application realistically, however if the WebSocket were to disconnect it would be shown too.

My question is, for performance reasons, should I be removing the element from the DOM entirely and add it back if its required? Does the fact that the overlay is completely transparent when not in use and the loader animation is hidden mean they have no impact on drawing performance?

Note: I am looking to avoid the "don't micro-optimise" answer if possible ;)

Comment: you can add `display: none` to remove it from the render tree instead of removing it from the DOM. i believe it is still in the render tree if it is transparent.

Comment: @keja, I was curious about it and made a test tool. Apparently, it's more expensive to add/remove from DOM than just change `opacity` and `pointer-events`. We're talking less than 1% of a ms though, so, in fact, it's insignificant.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i ment the rest of the page renderes faster as it has less elements in the render tree, lets say he adds new elements and you have 10k transparent vs 10k hidden. i ran your test on mac and got this btw:

`opacity average: 192.82865000000334ms | count: 100 ---------------------------
display average: 191.88055000000125ms | count: 100`

Comment: @keja: an element that doesn't change has no impact whatsoever on page performance, regardless of size. Only if it has ongoing animations, but most times those are CSS animations so they're extremely cheap. Most loaders have no footprint at all on page performance while running. I covered the exceptional case of having a very expensive  loader, saying it's the only case when it should be not displayed. On your tests, what browser did you use? Safari or Chrome?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Chrome, in Canary `opacity` wins & Safari does not like the test at all, only ran it once for each, because it almost froze, but got very different results in Safari: `display toggle took 34729.399999999994ms` & `opacity + pointer-events toggle took 33004.500000000015ms`

Comment: @keja, [`v8`](https://developers.google.com/v8/) always wins. It's that simple.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thats not true, jsc beats v8 in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

In general, a rendered element affects page performance when changes to it trigger repaint on subsequent elements in DOM or when it triggers `resize` on its parent(s), as `resize` can get expensive from being fired up to 100 times/second, depending on device.

---

As long as changes to your element do not trigger repaint on subsequent elements in DOM tree, the difference between having it rendered, hidden behind some opaque element (or above the content, with `opacity:0` and `pointer-events:none`) and having it not displayed at all is insignificant.

Changes to your element ***will not trigger repaint on anything but itself***, because it has `position:fixed`. The same would be true if it had `position:absolute` or if the changes to it would be made through properties that do not trigger repaint on subsequent siblings, like `transform` and `opacity`.

Unless the loader is really heavy on the rendering engine (which is rarely the case — think WebGL loaders with 3d scenes, materials and lights mapping — in which case it would be better to not display it when not shown to the user), the difference would be so small that the real challenge is to measure this difference, performance wise.

In fact, I would not be surprised if having it rendered and only changing its `opacity` and `pointer-events` properties is not, overall, less expensive than toggling its `display` property, because the browser doesn't have to add/remove it from DOM each time you turn it on/off. But, again, the real question is: how do we measure it?

---

**Edit:** Actually, I made a small testing tool, with 10k modals. I got the following results, in Chrome, on Linux:

```
`opacity` average: 110.71340000000076ms | count: 100
`display` average: 155.47145000000017ms | count: 100
```

... so my assumption was correct: `display` is more expensive overall.

The `opacity` changes are mostly around `110ms` with few exceptions, while the `display` changes are faster when nodes are removed but slower when  added.

Feel free to test it yourself, in different browsers, on different systems:

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  let displayAvg = 0, displayCount = 0,
      opacityAvg = 0, opacityCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    $('body').append($('<div />', {
      class: 'modal',
      html:'10k &times; modal instances'
    }))
  }
  $(document)
    .on('click', '#display', function () {
      $('.modal').removeClass('opacity');
      let t0 = performance.now();
      $('.modal').toggleClass('display');
      setTimeout(function () {
        let t1 = performance.now();
        displayAvg += (t1 - t0);
        console.log(
          '`display` toggle took ' + 
          (t1 - t0) +
          'ms \n`display` average: ' + 
          (displayAvg / ++displayCount) + 
          'ms | count: ' + 
          displayCount
        );
      })
    })
    .on('click', '#opacity', function () {
      $('.modal').removeClass('display');
      let t0 = performance.now();
      $('.modal').toggleClass('opacity');
      setTimeout(function () {
        let t1 = performance.now();
        opacityAvg += (t1 - t0);
        console.log(
          '`opacity` + `pointer-events` toggle took ' + 
          (t1 - t0) + 
          'ms \n`opacity` average: ' + 
          (opacityAvg / ++opacityCount) + 
          'ms | count: ' + 
          opacityCount
        );
      });
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.buttons-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.modal {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.modal.display {
  display: none;
}
.modal.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
  <button id="display">Toggle `display`</button>&nbsp;
  <button id="opacity">Toggle `opacity` + `pointer-events`</button>
</div>
```

But this average is for 10k elements. Divide it by 10k and it's virtually no difference at all: we're talking less than 0.45% of a millisecond.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I used the word "opaque" when I meant "transparent". The overlay, when not in use, is in front of everything, but completely *transparent*

Comment: @Cheetah, got it. My answer still applies. Having it there with `pointer-events:none` and `position:fixed` will have close to no impact on the performance of your page. If you want me to, I can reformulate the answer for your specific case but, in a more general context, I think it points out when a rendered element does (not) affect page performance.

Comment: @Cheetah, just out of curiosity, I made a test tool. In Chrome, on Linux, it appears I was right. Feel free to test it in other browsers/systems. In theory, the results might be slightly changed by doing the changes via jQuery, but I don't think it matters too much. I could have made a vanilla version of it, but I feel lazy this morning. I might do it later in the day.

Answer (score 0):

If an element is animated with **'Animation'** property and its duration is infinite browser will continuously repaint the site and that will affect the site performance and lower the FPS.

However hiding elements with properties such as **Opacity:0;** will not do the trick because element is still in CSSOM rendering tree queue.

**Visibility:hidden;** and **display:none;** should do the trick based on CSSOM construction browser doesn't render hidden elements such as **display:none; & visibility:hidden**