# How can I tell why a Recalculate Style takes so long?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, opacity

I have a web application that is experiencing some lag when users click a button.  The situation is this:

We have a modal that starts with a `hidden` attribute, whose styles we overrode with `opacity: 0` (that is, adding `hidden` attribute does not actually hide the element - it's still on the page, just with opacity 0)

When the user clicks the "modal open button" we simply toggle the `hidden` attribute on the element.  This results in `opacity: 1` for the item, which transitions over a second.

There are quite a few elements in the modal - around 3000.  Chrome dev tools performance tab indicates that is the number of elements effected by a `Recalculate Style` that is taking upwards of half a second.

I am surprised that transitioning opacity would be so expensive - if I tax my browser (open like 50 expensive tabs), this `Recalculate Style` takes even longer.

1. are opacity transitions generally considered an expensive operation? I didn't think so - for example, [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782721/does-a-hidden-transparent-element-impact-rendering-performance)
2. is there a way to figure out which things are included in the `Recalculate Style`?  I don't know if there are other styles being inadvertently recalculated or if it's just the opacity for the modal's 3000 elements

FWIW, we are having a hard time replicating this behavior on Macs at all, mostly we are seeing it on Windows machines (browsers are inconsistent but we most consistently see this issue in Brave, sometimes in Chrome) Happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks!